# Initialize const variable

Tags: go, constants

How can I initialize `KILO` variable with `const` type?

```
const KILO = math.Pow10(3)
```

Because I have an errror

```
const initializer math.Pow10(3) is not a constant
```

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Constant declarations cannot contain function calls (with some exceptions, see below), they must be evaluated at compile time while a function call is carried out at runtime.

Quoting from [Spec: Constants:](https://golang.org/ref/spec#Constants)

> A constant value is represented by a [rune](https://golang.org/ref/spec#Rune_literals), [integer](https://golang.org/ref/spec#Integer_literals), [floating-point](https://golang.org/ref/spec#Floating-point_literals), [imaginary](https://golang.org/ref/spec#Imaginary_literals), or [string](https://golang.org/ref/spec#String_literals) literal, an identifier denoting a constant, a [constant expression](https://golang.org/ref/spec#Constant_expressions), a [conversion](https://golang.org/ref/spec#Conversions) with a result that is a constant, or the result value of some built-in functions such as `unsafe.Sizeof` applied to any value, `cap` or `len` applied to [some expressions](https://golang.org/ref/spec#Length_and_capacity), `real` and `imag` applied to a `complex` constant and complex applied to numeric constants.

And quoting from [Spec: Constant expressions:](http://Constant%20expressions%20may%20contain%20only%20constant%20operands%20and%20are%20evaluated%20at%20compile%20time.)

> Constant expressions may contain only [constant](https://golang.org/ref/spec#Constants) operands and are **evaluated at compile time**.

Note that there is a small set of (builtin) functions that may be called in constant declarations such as `unsafe.Sizeof()`, but generally you can't do that.

So just use

```
const Kilo = 1000  // Integer literal
```

Or

```
const Kilo = 1e3   // Floating-point literal
```

For an extensive introduction to Go constants, read blog post: [Constants](https://blog.golang.org/constants)

If for some reason you do need to call a function, you cannot store it in a constant, it must be a [variable](https://golang.org/ref/spec#Variables), e.g.:

```
var Kilo = math.Pow10(3)
```

Also see related [Writing powers of 10 as constants compactly](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34124294/writing-powers-of-10-as-constants-compactly/34145667#34145667).