# golang remove characters (used for readability) in const string at compile time (spaces, \n and \t)

Tags: string, go, constants

Spaces are useful to indent urls, sql queries to make it more readable.
Is there a way to remove characters from a const string at compile time in golang ?

```
ex: (runtime version)
const url = `https://example.com/path?
attr1=test
&attr2=test
`
// this is the code to be replaced
urlTrim := strings.Replace(
strings.Replace(url, "\n", "", -1)
)
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[Constant expressions](https://golang.org/ref/spec#Constant_expressions) cannot contain function calls (except a few built-in functions). So what you want cannot be done using a [raw string literal](https://golang.org/ref/spec#String_literals).

If your goal with using multiple lines is just for readability, simply use multiple literals and [concatenate](https://golang.org/ref/spec#String_concatenation) them:

```
const url = "https://example.com/path?" +
    "attr1=test" +
    "&attr2=test"
```

Try it on the [Go Playground](https://play.golang.org/p/UyB_znP7jUu).

See related question: [Initialize const variable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49028654/initialize-const-variable/49028713#49028713)